# Why is the diffraction pattern like the interference pattern as opposed to a smooth band?

Tags: interference, diffraction

Why are diffraction patterns similar to interference patterns? I understand interference patterns but I can't wrap my head around as to why the diffraction pattern would be similar? Does diffraction lend itself to interference? Is it not possible to have diffraction without interference at all?

Comment: They’re both similar because they are dependent on phase (difference) relation

Comment: most interference patterns come from diffraction , if a slit is too narrow id set smaller than one wavelength, you have diffraction but no interference pattern.